# How to append .ttl file in python rdflib

Tags: python, rdflib, turtle-rdf

I am working by using rdflib python library for .ttl file processing. I have some triples in the .ttl file but I want to append (update) the file by adding new triples to the existing .ttl file using python rdflib library. 
For example:
file1.ttl has 10 triples (subject->predicate->object) and I want to add 5 new triples to the same file by appending the .ttl file in python rdflib.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you just need to "add" the graph as per documentation: https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.2/merging.html

```
from rdflib import Graph

g1 = Graph()
g1.parse("file1.ttl", format="turtle")

g2 = Graph()
g2.parse("file2.ttl", format="turtle")

graph = g1 + g2

graph.serialize("file1.ttl", format="turtle")
```